Consul Issue while installing in Kubernetes using HELM
I am trying to install consul as a client in Kubernetes and join it to my existing Consul server. When I check the logs of the consul-consul-connect-injector pod, I see the server is successflly connected
[INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager.consul-server-connection-manager: trying to connect to a Consul server
[INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager.consul-server-connection-manager: current prioritized list of known Consul servers: addresses=[192.168.60.10:8502]
[INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager.consul-server-connection-manager: connected to Consul server: address=192.168.60.10:8502
[INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager.consul-server-connection-manager: updated known Consul servers from watch stream: addresses=[192.168.60.10:8502]
[INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager.consul-server-connection-manager: updated known Consul servers from watch stream: addresses=[192.168.60.10:8502]

However, during the process I am getting the follow errors:
ERROR   error fetching config entries for kind: http-route      {"error": "Get \"http://192.168.60.10:8501/v1/config/http-route?dc=dc1\": context canceled"}
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).subscribeToConsul
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:223
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).Run.func1
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:188
2024-09-01T11:11:10.889Z        ERROR   error fetching config entries for kind: api-gateway     {"error": "Get \"http://192.168.60.10:8501/v1/config/api-gateway?dc=dc1\": context canceled"}
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).subscribeToConsul
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:223
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).Run.func1
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:188
2024-09-01T11:11:10.889Z        ERROR   error fetching config entries for kind: jwt-provider    {"error": "Get \"http://192.168.60.10:8501/v1/config/jwt-provider?dc=dc1\": context canceled"}
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).subscribeToConsul
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:223
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).Run.func1
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:188
2024-09-01T11:11:10.889Z        ERROR   error fetching config entries for kind: tcp-route       {"error": "Get \"http://192.168.60.10:8501/v1/config/tcp-route?dc=dc1\": context canceled"}
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).subscribeToConsul
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:223
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).Run.func1
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:188
2024-09-01T11:11:10.889Z        ERROR   error fetching config entries for kind: file-system-certificate {"error": "Get \"http://192.168.60.10:8501/v1/config/file-system-certificate?dc=dc1\": context canceled"}
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).subscribeToConsul
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:223
github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache.(*Cache).Run.func1
        /home/runner/work/consul-k8s/consul-k8s/control-plane/api-gateway/cache/consul.go:188
2024-09-01T11:11:10.891Z        INFO    starting server {"kind": "health probe", "addr": "[::]:9445"}
2024-09-01T11:11:10.987Z        INFO    controller-runtime.webhook      Starting webhook server
2024-09-01T11:11:10.988Z        INFO    controller-runtime.certwatcher  Updated current TLS certificate
2024-09-01T11:11:10.988Z        INFO    controller-runtime.webhook      Serving webhook server  {"host": "", "port": 8080}
2024-09-01T11:11:10.988Z        INFO    controller-runtime.certwatcher  Starting certificate watcher
2024-09-01T11:11:11.588Z        INFO    attempting to acquire leader lease consul/consul-controller-lock...

2024-09-01T11:11:11.587Z        INFO    Stopping and waiting for non leader election runnables
2024-09-01T11:11:11.588Z        INFO    Stopping and waiting for leader election runnables
2024-09-01T11:11:11.589Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "endpoints", "controllerGroup": "", "controllerKind": "Endpoints", "source": "kind source: *v1.Endpoints"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.589Z        INFO    Starting Controller     {"controller": "endpoints", "controllerGroup": "", "controllerKind": "Endpoints"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.589Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "gatewayclass", "controllerGroup": "gateway.networking.k8s.io", "controllerKind": "GatewayClass", "source": "kind source: *v1beta1.GatewayClass"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.589Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "gatewayclass", "controllerGroup": "gateway.networking.k8s.io", "controllerKind": "GatewayClass", "source": "kind source: *v1alpha1.GatewayClassConfig"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.687Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "servicedefaults", "controllerGroup": "consul.hashicorp.com", "controllerKind": "ServiceDefaults", "source": "kind source: *v1alpha1.ServiceDefaults"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.687Z        INFO    Starting Controller     {"controller": "servicedefaults", "controllerGroup": "consul.hashicorp.com", "controllerKind": "ServiceDefaults"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.687Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "gateway", "controllerGroup": "gateway.networking.k8s.io", "controllerKind": "Gateway", "source": "kind source: *v1beta1.Gateway"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.687Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "gateway", "controllerGroup": "gateway.networking.k8s.io", "controllerKind": "Gateway", "source": "kind source: *v1.Deployment"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.687Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "gateway", "controllerGroup": "gateway.networking.k8s.io", "controllerKind": "Gateway", "source": "kind source: *v1alpha2.TCPRoute"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.687Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "gateway", "controllerGroup": "gateway.networking.k8s.io", "controllerKind": "Gateway", "source": "kind source: *v1.Secret"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.688Z        INFO    Starting EventSource    {"controller": "servicerouter", "controllerGroup": "consul.hashicorp.com", "controllerKind": "ServiceRouter", "source": "kind source: *v1alpha1.ServiceRouter"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.688Z        INFO    Stopping and waiting for caches
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1.Endpoints Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1.Endpoints Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ServiceDefaults Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.GatewayClassConfig Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.RouteAuthFilter Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1.Secret Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        INFO    Stopping and waiting for webhooks
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1.Service Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1.Pod Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1beta1.ReferenceGrant Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ProxyDefaults Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ServiceResolver Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ExportedServices Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.689Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ServiceSplitter Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ServiceRouter Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.IngressGateway Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ServiceIntentions Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.SamenessGroup Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.TerminatingGateway Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.ControlPlaneRequestLimit Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.JWTProvider Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.PollUntilContextCancel
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/poll.go:33
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:56
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        ERROR   controller-runtime.source.EventHandler  failed to get informer from cache       {"error": "Timeout: failed waiting for *v1alpha1.TerminatingGateway Informer to sync"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/source.(*Kind).Start.func1.1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.16.5/pkg/internal/source/kind.go:68
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext.func1
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:49
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.loopConditionUntilContext
        /home/runner/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.28.9/pkg/util/wait/loop.go:50

2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        INFO    controller-runtime.webhook      Shutting down webhook server with timeout of 1 minute
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        INFO    Stopping and waiting for HTTP servers
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        INFO    shutting down server    {"kind": "health probe", "addr": "[::]:9445"}
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        INFO    controller-runtime.metrics      Shutting down metrics server with timeout of 1 minute
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z        INFO    Wait completed, proceeding to shutdown the manager
2024-09-01T11:11:11.690Z [INFO]  consul-server-connection-manager.consul-server-connection-manager: stopping

Below are my config files in server
cat /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl | grep -v "#"
data_dir = "/opt/consul"
client_addr = "0.0.0.0"

ui_config{
  enabled = true
}

server = true 
advertise_addr = "192.168.60.10"
bootstrap_expect=1
retry_join = ["192.168.60.10"]

ports {
 grpc = 8502
} 

This is my custom values.yaml file I am using to install Consul on K8S
global:
  enabled: false
  tls:
    enabled: false
externalServers:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["192.168.60.10"]
server:
  enabled: false

I am trying to use Consul dataplane without using the clients as per Consul

With the introduction of Consul Dataplane, Consul installation on
Kubernetes is simplified by removing the Consul Client agents. This
requires the Helm installation and rest of the consul-k8s components
installed on Kubernetes to talk to Consul Servers directly on various
ports. Before starting the installation, ensure that the Consul
Servers are configured to have the gRPC port enabled 8502/tcp using
the ports.grpc = 8502 configuration option.

I am not sure if I am missing something here. I sincerely grateful for any help to figure this out.
Thank you!

You should add httpsPort: 8500 in the helm-values.yaml too
global:
  enabled: false
  tls:
    enabled: false
externalServers:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["192.168.60.10"]
  httpsPort: 8500
server:
  enabled: false


Thank you so much! consul-connect-injector pod started successfully. Could you please tell me why we are adding http port 8500 as https port here.
Also, I am bit confused on what configurations to use where. For example I am using helm to install consul on K8s link. I am also using /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl which was already available after installation to setup server configs. But, I am confused to which docs I should refer to get the server configs and syntax. Could you kindly give me some hints please. tx

I'm using this link you shared too, Each helm chart has its own default values. when you are using consul helm chart, it has its own default values(described in the link). So the dafault values for httpsPort is 8501 and your consul is running on 8500 so you should change httpsPort to 8500.

Thank you! I actually installed consul as a server on a VM using link. I didn't use helm at all. There was already a consul.hcl inside /etc/consul.d/ directory with some default values. I only added ports  myself there thinking it might work. However, I couldn't find any doc to see how we should add the port and what are available parameters when we are not using helm. Also, I think helm is only for k8s installs. May be I haven't found although I tried to search many times :(
